# Questions on cookie

Tags: cookies

Need help on the following questions regarding cookie

1. I'm developing a standalone jar which access a http site inside the code. When i access the http site will the cookie will be stored in the client machine ??
2. When the cookie will be saved in client's machine ?
3. The cookie will be stored only when we access web application via browser or via any library and executing http request
4. When and how the cookie can be enabled or disabled in a client's machine.

Thanks.

Comment: How does your jar access the HTTP site? could share your sample code.?

Comment: Normally using HttpClient library. why? it is working without any issues.

Comment: https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/quickstart.html

Comment: So your Java application are behaving like the browser, so that you need inspect the HTTP response and store the cookies your self.

Comment: How to store the cookie in java..assume i am using HttpClient from Apache Commons. please suggest

Comment: Basically you need a cookie store, I have put some sample code in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your java application will need create a cookie store and link it to the HttpClient. For example

```
CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
// Populate cookies if needed
BasicClientCookie cookie = new BasicClientCookie("name", "value");
cookie.setDomain(".mycompany.com");
cookie.setPath("/");
cookieStore.addCookie(cookie);
// Set the store
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
        .setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore)
        .build();
```

Reference: https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/statemgmt.html